# How do I use equalsTo() in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure of:

```
newsfeed-21f5c

 newsfeed3:9:2016:18:1:39
   text: "5"
   time: "3:9:2016:18:1:39"
   timeStampFirebase: 1475661721607
 newsfeed4:9:2016:11:16:10
   number: 7
   time: "4:9:2016:11:16:10"
   timeStampFirebase: 1475723771672
```

And I tried running:

```
var search = firebase.database().ref("newsfeed");
  search.orderByChild("number").equalTo(7).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
  });
```

And I keep getting a Firebase warning.

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "number" at /newsfeed to your security rules for better performance

What I'm trying to achieve is to search for `newsfeeds` with the key of number that is equal to `7`.

I'm pretty new to Firebase so all help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does the warning say?

Comment: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "number" at /newsfeed to your security rules for better performance

Comment: Not to sure what it means. But I used the same method the example showed in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are getting,

`FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "number" at /newsfeed to your security rules for better performance`

is not an error. Your code should work.
Firebase supports indexing, which can drastically improve the speed of searches like this one. The warning you are seeing is Firebase asking you to configure the index for better performance.

How to do so:

Go to your Firebase console.

Look under Database -> Rules (one of the tabs).

There you can set permission rules AND indexes in JSON format. Copy paste this JSON in there:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "newsfeed": {
      ".indexOn": ["number"]
    }
  }
}
```

PS: use `snapshot.getKey()` to get the firebase key.

Comment: like this:                  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
    "newsfeed": {
      ".indexOn": ["number"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: how do I add it to my existing rules?

Comment: Yes, like that. You are missing a comma before "newsfeed", though.

Comment: got it thx, Im not getting the warning anymore, but when I console log snapshot.key nothing seems to be coming out,

Comment: use `snapshot.getKey()`

Comment: The function is only called when a new child is added, as per the "child_added" event.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I'll look into it more. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

The warning is saying you should define an index on the `number` field, since you're querying by that field. Basically, if you tell Firebase in advance what you'll be querying on, they can manage your data internally to better support that query by creating an index.